# I'm adding a icon to the front of anchor tags however, I want to stop it from adding the icon multple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Want to limit the icon from being added multiple times per anchor tag.

If you keep clicking on any of the links(foo, bar, baz) multiple times, it will just keep adding many times.

Any ideas how to stop this?

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  $('<a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color: #ccc;"></i></a>').insertBefore($(this))
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a>foo</a>
<br>
<a>bar</a>
<br>
<a>baz</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use jQuery [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method. 
This way your code will be executed at most once per element per `click` event.

Code:

```js
$('a').one('click', function() {
  $('<a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color: #ccc;"></i></a>').insertBefore($(this))
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a>foo</a>
<br>
<a>bar</a>
<br>
<a>baz</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add icon add class to that anchor too, later check if it already have that class. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/68p8pe4o/)

```
$('a').click(function() {
if(!$(this).hasClass('have-icon')) {
$(this).addClass('have-icon')
  $('<a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color: #ccc;"></i></a>').insertBefore($(this))
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try like that , remove glyphicon on click of button and add glyphicon after removing old one,,, i think that will help you....

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a').click(function() {
   var aa=$(this).prev('a:has(>i)').remove()
  // console.log(aa)
  $('<a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color: #ccc;"></i></a>').insertBefore($(this))
});
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a>foo</a>
<br>
<a>bar</a>
<br>
<a>baz</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a CSS class to the elements that already have added an item before.

```
$('a').click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('item-already-added') == false)
  {
      $('<a href="#">...').insertBefore($(this));
      $(this).addClass('item-already-added');
  }
});
```